# Richfaces 4.2 push with jms

Tags: richfaces

Has anyone been able to use jms with richfaces 4.2 with success?

I'd be interested in usage, where the message/notification is published in the applications businesstier/integration tier and consumed in the view layer.

Consider 3 logged in users A,B and c

How i  can be sure that notification published is consumed only by consumer A. Subtopics, message selectors??

Or is this whole scenario not fit for jms/richfaces push. Is it meant to be used only across the view layer??

Answer (score 0):

I use JMS push notification with richfaces 4.3 and JBOSS AS7. Read my brief explanation to implement subtopic: [Creating subtopic with JMS push](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingSubtopicWithJMSPush)